# Isometric immersions of $S^2$ to $S^4$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

There are non-standard isometric immersions of the sphere $S^2(r)$ of radius $0<r<4$ into the unit sphere $S^4$. Such immersion have been constructed in [1]. As shown in [1], these immersions are actually isometric embeddings when $0<r<1.6$. In particular we have a non-standard isometric embedding of the unit sphere $S^2$ into $S^4$.

> Is there an isometric immersion of the unit sphere $S^2$ into $S^4$
>   which is not an embedding (has self-intersections)?

[1] **D. Ferus, U. Pinkall,** Constant curvature 2-spheres in the 4-sphere. *Math. Z.* 200 (1989), 265-271.

EDIT: The Veronese embedding mentioned by j.c. in his comment is described [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=U2BIz8NNksYC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=isometric+embedding+veronese+s2+s4&source=bl&ots=OH1oQjfXZv&sig=w8_Q23diY-F9voe_Lcdfj_d_JXw&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3kfK6gbvbAhXlw1kKHdYJCiEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=isometric%20embedding%20veronese%20s2%20s4&f=false).

EDIT2: The examples show that there are isometric immersions of $S^2(r)$ into the unit sphere $S^4$ that have self-intersections for $r<1$ and for some $r>1$. The original question about the case $r=1$ is **still not answered**.

Comment: A non-example: there is an isometric immersion of the 2-sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$ as the double cover of the Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into the unit $S^4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple source of such immersions for $r<1$.

Consider geodesic subspheres $\mathbb{S}^2\subset \mathbb{S}^3\subset \mathbb{S}^4$.
Take a closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{S}^2$.
Pass to its spherical suspension; it is embedded in $\mathbb{S}^3$.
Pass to the spherical suspension again; you get an immersed singular surface $\Sigma^3$ in $\mathbb{S}^4$ which admits an immersion of hemisphere $$\iota\colon\mathbb{S}^3_+\looparrowright\Sigma^3.$$

Note that for $r<1$, there are isometric embeddings $f\colon\mathbb{S}^2(r)\to \mathbb{S}^3_+$ and for the right choice of $f$ and $\gamma$, the composition $\iota\circ f\colon\mathbb{S}^2(r)\to \mathbb{S}^4$ has self-intersections.

Comment: I do not understand this construction. Can you add a bit more details? What is the regularity of your mapping $f$? I am interested in the immersions that are at least $C^2$.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz It is $C^\infty$; let's put it this way: there are plenty smooth deformations of $\mathbb{S}^3_+$ in $\mathbb{S}^4$; some of them have self-intersections. We embed $\mathbb{S}^2(r)$ into $\mathbb{S}^3_+$  and bend $\mathbb{S}^3_+$ to produce self-intersection for the composition.

Comment: Can you do it with the unit sphere $r=1$? That is precisely what I need.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz, the construction works only for $r<1$.